# Should modifying an inline member function cause recompiling the whole class?

Tags: c++, inline-functions

Hello I know that if the compiler inlines a function, it replaces its body (statements) in each call to it.

I've read this from Stroustrup's programming principles and practice using c++ about defining a class member function within the class body:

> All uses of the class will have to be recompiled whenever we make a change to the body of an inlined function. If the function body is out of the class declaration, recompilation of users is needed only when the class declaration is itself changed. Not recompiling when the body is changed can be a huge advantage in large programs.

- So for example:

  ```
  struct Foo{
     void say_hello(std::string const& msg){ std::cout << "Hello " << msg << '\n'}; //implicitly inlined
     int getVal() const{ return som_val;} // implicitly inlined 
     inline void bar(); // maybe inline, defined outside
  };

  void Foo::bar(){}

  Foo the_foo;
  the_foo.say_hello("world");
  ```
- Does he mean that if I change the body of `say_hello` will cause the whole class be recompiled?
- If so then what is the difference between `say_hello` and `bar`? the latter is marked inline but defined outside of the class body.

Can someone explain to me what he means and the mechanism of inlining and not recompiling and when recompiling is needed with small examples? Thank you so much!

Comment: This might be a good time to learn about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). The compiler only deals in translation units, and will need to parse and compile the full translation unit. It doesn't selectively compile individual functions or classes.

Comment: There is not much difference here. When Bjarne says *"out of the class declaration,"* he means that the body is in a separate .cpp file. In that case only that .cpp file will have to be recompiled. (Only works for functions that are not `inline`)

Comment: He's basically telling you that there's benefit in not having to modify your header file, since every translation unit including a header file needs to be recompiled on a modification, even if they are included indirectly. If you've got the implementation in a seperate file, you only need to recompile the implementation file and then directly continue with linking...

Comment: @BoP: So he means inline vs non-inline function as long as an inline function must be defined in the header file rather than in a source  file since it is definition is needed at compile-time?

Comment: @fabian: having its definition is a separate source file makes it non inline so he does he mean inline vs non-inline functions?

Comment: Actually the compiler doesn't really have to inline it. Defining a function in header file allows for inlining, but doesn't force the compiler. If you ever use a pointer to `&Foo::say_hello` you may be sure it will be generated as a separate code block, but in some parts of code it can be inlined despite this block is already generated. Decision is all on the compiler. The recompilation should be done because the content of the translation unit is modified - doesn't matter if the function content changes, or a field or include list, or even macro definition.

Comment: Maestro: Important note for what you are trying to grasp: the `inline` keyword does not deal with function inlining. Yeah it is confusing. Function inlining happens at the discretion of the compiler and that's pretty much it, barring non-standard, compiler-specific directives.

Comment: @spectras True, but putting the function definition into a separate cpp file, compiling everything and then changing the function definition in that cpp file, only this file has to be recompiled. (There can be further optimizations at link time). With inlined functions on the other hand all translation units calling that function (or actually all including the inline definition) have to be recompiled. Regardless whether the function is actually inlined or not (or sometimes).

Comment: @Sebastian indeed. Thus the importance of dissociating the two concepts of function inlining and function-marked-with-`inline`. And anyway, neither is directly relevant; as others explained above all that matters is whether we modify the header or not.

Comment: I think you misread that statement, too: "the class has to be recompiled" is not the same as "uses of the class have to be recompiled"!